# How to fix wallpaper problem?

Tags: desktop-background

every time I shutdown/restart my laptop, my wallpaper always resets to blank blue and I have to re-apply my custom wallpaper. I have ubuntu 12.04 with current updates. I didn't have this problem for a long time and it just started doing it randomly a few months ago. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your startup applications:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/serrano/Pictures/x.jpg
```

Change the path, but the `file://` at the beginning is important, and cannot be removed.

To add it to startup applications:

Click the Cog `⚙` and then Startup Applications.

[image]

Click Add

[image]

Enter the details and click save.

[image]

It should set the image on startup.

Comment: Still not working. I tried this command, gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///media/5058-F505/Documents/Pictures/coloredgeometry.jpg , so I'm not sure why it is not working.

Comment: maybe it doesn't like it being on media?

Comment: /media is a different partition, so I will try putting on the same file system as the OS and see if that works.

Comment: No, external media works, just tried it myself... Make sure the path is exact, try dragging the file to the terminal to insert the exact path - delete the `''` at the beginning and end.

Comment: Well I changed both the file location and the command so it would reflect the change so not sure which one did it but it's working now so thanks.

Comment: Okay good, glad to help :)